# Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Boolean' - maybe not public or not valid?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a SpringBoot application for an e-commerce website project where I'm creating a form to change the current password of the user account. I am getting the following two errors when the form gets submitted.

1. ERROR-1

```
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/myprofile.html]")

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.id" (template: "myprofile" - line 110, col 68)

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.id" (template: "myprofile" - line 110, col 68)
```

2. ERROR-2

```
Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Boolean' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

**HomeController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUserInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public String updateUserInfo(
              
              @ModelAttribute("user") user user,
              @ModelAttribute("newPassword") String newPassword,
              Model model
              ) throws Exception{
          
          user currentUser = userService.findById(user.getId());
          
          if(currentUser == null) {
              throw new Exception ("User not found.");
          }
          
          if(userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail())!=null) {
              if(userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).getId() != currentUser.getId()) {
                  model.addAttribute("emailExists", true);
                  return "myprofile";
              }
          }
          
          if(userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername())!=null) {
              if(userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).getId() != currentUser.getId()) {
                  model.addAttribute("usernameExists", true);
                  return "myprofile";
              }
          }
          
          if(newPassword != null && !newPassword.isEmpty() && !newPassword .equals("")) {
              BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
              String dbPassword = currentUser.getPassword();
              if(passwordEncoder.matches(user.getPassword(), dbPassword)) {
                  currentUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
              }else {
                  model.addAttribute("invalidPassword", true);
                  return "myprofile";
              }
          }
          
          currentUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
          currentUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());
          currentUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
          currentUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
          
          userService.save(currentUser);
          
          model.addAttribute("updateSuccess", true);
          model.addAttribute("user", true);
          model.addAttribute("classActiveEdit", true);
          
          UserDetails userDetails = userSecurityService.loadUserByUsername(currentUser.getUsername());
            
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
            
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); 
            
            return "myprofile";
      }
```

**myprofile.html**

```
<form th:action="@{/updateUserInfo}" method="post" >
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${user.id}" />
                                    <div class="bg-info" th:if="${updateUserInfo}">User info updated</div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" th:value="${user.firstName}" />
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" th:value="${user.lastName}" />
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="userName">Username</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" name="username" th:value="${user.username}" />
                                     </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="currentPassword">Current Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="currentPassword" name="password" th:value="${currentPassword}" />
                                    </div>
                                    <p style="color: #828282">Enter your current password to change the email address or password</p>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" th:value="${user.email}" />
                                    </div>
                                    <p style="color: #828282">A valid email address. All
                                        emails from the system will be sent to this address.The
                                        email address is not make public and will only be used if
                                        you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive
                                        certain notification</p>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtNewPassword">Password</label>&nbsp;<span id="checkPasswordMatch" style="color:red;"></span>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtNewPassword" name="txtNewPassword"  />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtConfirmPassword" />
                                    </div>
                                    <p style="color: #828282">To change the current user password, enter new password in both fileds </p>


                                    <button id="updateUserInfobutton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save All</button>
                   </form>
```

**User Class**

```
package com.eshop.domian;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.eshop.security.UserRole;
import com.eshop.security.auth;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
public class user implements UserDetails{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name="email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private boolean enabled=true;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserShipping> userShippingList;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserPayment> userPaymentList;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles= new HashSet<>();
    
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }
    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
    
    public ShoppingCart getShoppingCart() {
        return shoppingCart;
    }
    public void setShoppingCart(ShoppingCart shoppingCart) {
        this.shoppingCart = shoppingCart;
    }
    public List<UserShipping> getUserShippingList() {
        return userShippingList;
    }
    public void setUserShippingList(List<UserShipping> userShippingList) {
        this.userShippingList = userShippingList;
    }
    public List<UserPayment> getUserPaymentList() {
        return userPaymentList;
    }
    public void setUserPaymentList(List<UserPayment> userPaymentList) {
        this.userPaymentList = userPaymentList;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.forEach(ur -> authorities.add(new auth(ur.getRole().getName())));
        
        return authorities;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled()
    {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

**User Service**

```
package com.eshop.service;

import java.util.Set;

import com.eshop.domian.UserBilling;
import com.eshop.domian.UserPayment;
import com.eshop.domian.UserShipping;
import com.eshop.domian.user;
import com.eshop.security.PasswordResetToken;
import com.eshop.security.UserRole;

public interface UserService {
    
    PasswordResetToken getPasswordResetToken(final String token);
    
     void createPasswordResetTokenForUser(final user user, final String token);
     
     user findByUsername(String username);

     user findByEmail(String email);
     
     user findById(Long Id);

     user createUser(user user, Set<UserRole> userRoles) throws Exception;

     user save(user user);
     
     void updateUserBilling(UserBilling userBilling, UserPayment userPayment, user user);
     
     void setUserDefaultPayment(Long userPaymentId, user user);
     
     void updateUserShipping(UserShipping userShipping, user user);
     
     void setUserDefaultShipping(Long userShippingId, user user);

}
```

**User Service Implementation**

```
package com.eshop.service.impl;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

@Autowired
private PasswordResetTokenRepository passwordResetTokenRepository;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
private UserPaymentRepository userPaymentRepository;

@Autowired
private UserShippingRepository userShippingRepository;

@Override
public PasswordResetToken getPasswordResetToken(final String token) {
    return passwordResetTokenRepository.findByToken(token);
}

@Override
public void createPasswordResetTokenForUser(final user user, final String token) {
    final PasswordResetToken myToken = new PasswordResetToken(token, user);
    passwordResetTokenRepository.save(myToken);
}

@Override
public user findByUsername(String username) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userRepository.findByusername(username);
}

@Override
public user findById(Long id) {
    return userRepository.findById(id).get(); 
}

@Override
public user findByEmail(String email) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you try to access the `id` field of the `user` model attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${user.id}" />
```

Here you set the `user` model attribute to `true`, therefore it's of type `boolean`:

```
model.addAttribute("user", true);
```

As a variable of type `boolean` does not have a field called `id`, trying to access it gives the error you see. I assume what's going on is that you didn't want to set that model attribute to `true` (perhaps you wanted to set it to `currentUser`?), or that the `id` field that you want to access belongs to another model attribute.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. It has to be `model.addAttribute("user", currentUser);`